# bootstrap and custom css / remove radio button in custom radio field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am using bootstrap as core css but also have a custom css file for various modifications however my custom radio field has a span class inserted that I cannot seem to remove. Where do I start to try and locate this or remove it by using my custom.css file

[image]

custom.css

```
/* pricing switcher */
.pricing-switcher {
    text-align: center;
}

.pricing-switcher .fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 50em;
    border: 2px solid #2d3e50;
}

.pricing-switcher input.pricing-input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

input.pricing-input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.pricing-switcher label {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.pricing-switcher .switch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: #2d3e50;
    border-radius: 50em;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.pricing-switcher input.pricing-input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .switch,
.pricing-switcher input.pricing-input[type="radio"]:checked + label:nth-of-type(n) + .switch {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(90px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(90px);
    -o-transform: translateX(90px);
    transform: translateX(90px);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="pricing-switcher">
 <p class="fieldset">
    <input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="monthly" id="monthly-1" class="pricing-input" checked>
    <label for="monthly-1">Per-Use</label>
    <input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="yearly" id="yearly-1" class="pricing-input">
    <label for="yearly-1">Monthly</label>
        <span class="switch"></span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Here is the compiled HTML viewing the page.

```
<div class="pricing-switcher">    
<p class="fieldset">
    <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-circle-o fa-base"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-base"></span></span><input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="monthly" id="monthly-1" class="pricing-input" checked="">
    <label for="monthly-1">Per-Use</label>
    <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-circle-o fa-base"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-base"></span></span><input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="yearly" id="yearly-1" class="pricing-input">
    <label for="yearly-1">Monthly</label>
    <span class="switch"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is how it should look without the original bootstrap radio field
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvmJdW

Comment: Cant you just hide the element with `.pricing-switcher .switch { display: none; }` ?

Comment: @crazymatt that wont work as it hides the custom switch. see my edits above for the compiled html. there is the <span class="icons"> that I need to get rid of.

Comment: Ahh okay makes more sense now. Do you have a codepen or fiddle with an example of your code?

Comment: @crazymatt added link for codepen. Trying to replicate my issue on codepen however it works how it should on there.

Comment: This is the whole custom.css or have more code, which version of bootstrap you using are?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.5. yes that is all for the custom.css

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you everyone for getting my brain thinking. It happened to be actually being a bootstrap.js file (bootstrap-checkbox-radio.js)... face palm!